# Prove that $\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{k+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I try to prove that $\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{k+1}$ for all integers k greater or equal to 1 but don't know how to transform this equation full of square roots in order to finish the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$1=k+1-k=(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)$$

$$\implies\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k=?$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$$

Comment: I like this answer the best. Very simple, and obviously implying to multiply both sides by $\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}}$ and by $\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}$.

You will get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{-\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} \cdot (-\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}$$

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, find a common denominator.

$\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}= \frac{\sqrt{k}(\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}) + 1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}}$

Next, distribute.

$\frac{k + \sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1} + 1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}}$

Now, we rearrange the terms so we have

$\frac{k + 1 + \sqrt{k}\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}}$

Now factor out of the numerator a $\sqrt{k+1}$

$\frac{\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k})}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1}}$

Cancel out common terms, and now we have our answer.